# Haskell: Illegal Instance declaration for show / recursive data type

Tags: haskell

I've been searching a lot for this but I've not found something solid.

I'm making my own module with my own data type, and then I tried to make a show instance, and that was when things got messy. I'll show you

```
data listOfFav a = Insert (a,Bool) (listOfFav a) | Empty deriving (Show)

instance Show a => Show (listOfFav a) where
  show = ('{' :) . go
   where
      go Empty                 = "}"
      go (Insert (x,y) Vazia)  = show x ++ show y ++ "}"
      go (Insert (x,y) xs)     = show x ++ show y ++", " ++ go xs
```

And for some reason I got this error:

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘Show (listaFavoritos a)’
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for ‘Show (listaFavoritos a)’
```

I would be very thankfull if someone could help me

Comment: Try capitalizing listOfFav to `ListOfFav` everywhere it appears. You'll also need to replace Vazia with Empty to resolve an unknown-type error. You'll also need to remove the `deriving (Show)`, as it conflicts with your hand-spun one.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell requires that data types start with a capital letter. Your code should look like this:

```
data ListOfFav a = Insert (a,Bool) (ListOfFav a) | Empty

instance Show a => Show (ListOfFav a) where
  show = ('{' :) . go
   where
      go Empty                 = "}"
      go (Insert (x,y) Empty)  = show x ++ show y ++ "}"
      go (Insert (x,y) xs)     = show x ++ show y ++", " ++ go xs
```

Furthermore, Haskell only allows one `Show` instance per datatype. Either you use `deriving Show` to let the Haskell compiler create one for you or you write your own, but you cannot do both. In the code above I removed the `deriving Show` to let the handwritten instance take precedence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the capital letter, I'm so stupid lost 30 mins on that, the orginal problem was that ListOfFav was written with a capital L on the data, with a 'l' on the instance. Thank You :)